# Error when connecting H2 with symmetricDS using jdbc

Tags: database, connection, h2, symmetricds

Im trying to create a database connection between H2 and SymmetricDS in a ***virtual machine***. Following this toturial ([H2-Installation](https://o7planning.org/11895/install-h2-database-and-use-h2-console)), Im able to install H2 and create store001 H2 database using H2-browser. However, when I connect to SymmetricDS, it throws some error on the connection.

Symmetric config:

```
db.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.url=jdbc:h2:~/store001;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000
```

H2 config (in h2.sh):

```
java -cp "$dir/h2-1.4.200.jar:$H2DRIVERS:$CLASSPATH" org.h2.tools.Server -web -webAllowOthers -ifNotExists "$@"
```

H2 Browser (managed to create store-001):

[image]

Error when running symmetricDS using H2 jdbc connection:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "/root/store001 outside /opt/symmetric-server-3.12.10/db/h2" [90028-176]
```

These are steps I tried to solve this issue:

1. Adding ***-Dh2.baseDir=/*** in h2.sh. Following this solution -> [solution-example](https://sourceforge.net/p/symmetricds/discussion/739237/thread/33c8a23b/)

But got this error when running H2:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Feature not supported: "-Dh2.baseDir=/" [50100-200]
```

2. Change H2 Browser from `Embedded` to `Server`. But got this error in browser:

`Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused): localhost" [90067-200] 90067/90067 (Help`)

What should i do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

SymmetricDS is using version 1.3.176 for H2.

Use the 1.3.176 H2 jar file from the SymmetricDS installation:
java -cp /opt/symmetric-ds/web/WEB-INF/lib/h2-1.3.176.jar::$H2DRIVERS:$CLASSPATH" org.h2.tools.Server -web -webAllowOthers -ifNotExists "$@"

You can specify the H2 URL to be as follows when you create the file:
jdbc:h2:/opt/symmetric-ds/tmp/h2/store001